# We remain at your service

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to sign off using "We remain at your service."? Are the following any better?

We remain at your disposal.
We remain at your disposition.

or remove "remain":

We are at your service.
We are at your disposal.
etc...

or something even better that I haven't thought of!

Comment: "We remain at your disposition" would be much more unusual than the other two, because the primary meaning of 'disposition' in modern times is "a person's inherent qualities of mind and character", as in "a happy disposition" or "an irritable disposition".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each of those is grammatically correct. The convention regarding

> We remain at your service.

is that it's a relatively short, slightly formal way of saying

> We have been in your service, we are now at your service, and will continue to do so as well.

Forever your servant.

--Chemus.